# How to convert numeric into varchar in sql

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

Can someone suggest which is the best method to insert numeric value as `varchar` in SQL Server.

Scenario: I have a staging table in which I am getting data from another source. One column `receipt number` is of a numeric datatype in my table because data which I am receiving is also from a numeric column.

So it looks like below once I get data in my staging table

```
RECEIPT_NUMBER
--------------
1201576.0000
```

My main table has this receipt number column as type `varchar`. When I insert data in my main table it looks like below:

```
MAIN_RECEIPT_NUMBER
--------------------
1.20158E+006
```

Can anyone suggest me what is the best approach to get this data in below format in my main table

```
MAIN_RECEIPT_NUMBER
--------------------
1201576
```

Comment: Are you sure `Receipt_Number` is of data type `numeric`? `1.20158e+006` looks like it was a `float` value converted to `varchar`.

Comment: Hi receipt number is nvarchar

Comment: `Receipt_Number` is `nvarchar`? Ok then, what data type is `Main_Receipt_Number` - is it a `float` column?

Answer (score 0):

tryusing

to_char(numeric_value). This may solve your issue.

Comment: `to_char()` is an Oracle function. The question is tagged with `sql-server`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
convert(nvarchar(18),convert(bigint,RECEIPT_NUMBER))
```

You might lose the decimals.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but sql is throwing an error 'Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.'

Comment: Its fine if i loose decimals, Actually i want to get rid of decimal and all the zero follows.

Comment: do you have to specify the size (ie. `nvarchar(18)`)? Can I use `convert(varchar,convert(bigint,RECEIPT_NUMBER))`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All,

I manage to find a way

convert(varchar(40),convert(numeric(18),RECEIPT_NUMBER))

Comment: do you have to specify the size (ie. `varchar(40)`)? Can I use `convert(varchar,convert(numeric(18),RECEIPT_NUMBER))`